# Integrating Haste into Stack tool chain

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haste

I am using [Haskell Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) for a project and I want to include [Haste](http://haste-lang.org/) it compile client side logic. I like the fact that Stack abstracts away the different build and install issues among environments and if it builds on my machine, it will build on someone else's.

How do I integrate Haste into the Stack tool chain?  Working out one time setup is fine, but I don't want to have to recreate the whole tool chain every time the code moves to a new system.

Comment: I don't know a Stack answer, but maybe you might want to step up to a full build system like [shake](http://shakebuild.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, but take that with a grain of salt as I'm having extra issues due to [this](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler/issues/375) known bug. Make sure your `.cabal` file has the right dependencies, especially the `if impl(haste) ..` part ([see this](http://haste-lang.org/blog/haste-and-cabal-files/)). Seems like most of the dependencies for Haste (and since Haste uses GHC 7.10.3 as of today) work with `lts-6.14`, so I used that as resolver.

**haste-project.cabal**

```
name:                haste-project
version:             0.1.0.0
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable haste-project-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base  >= 4.8 && < 4.9
  if impl(haste)
    build-depends:     haste-lib >= 0.5 && < 0.6
  else
    build-depends:     haste-compiler >= 0.5 && < 0.6
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

**stack.yaml**

```
extra-deps:
- HTTP-4000.2.23
- ghc-simple-0.3
- haste-compiler-0.5.4.2
- shellmate-0.2.3
resolver: lts-6.14
```

Then, from the same directory, you can now proceed with the [usual setup instructions for Haste](http://haste-lang.org/downloads/), but with Stack complements of the Cabal commands:

```sh
$ stack build
$ stack install haste-compiler # installs haste-boot, haste-cat, haste-pkg, and hastec
$ stack exec haste-boot        # setup Haste (where I get the bug I mentioned above)
```

Then, you should be able to run all the usual commands, but prefixed with `stack exec --`. For example

```sh
$ stack exec -- hastec -O2 -fglasgow-exts myprog.hs
```